# Where is this Errno::ENOENT error from?

Tags: ruby

Beginner here, teaching myself Ruby. I'm getting Errno::ENOENT and I think I figured out how, but I don't understand why I'm getting it. Here's the error:

```
Downloading 4 files:  .  .  . c11-photos.rb:29:in `rename': No such file or 
directory - (c:/users/7/dropbox/3-coding/ruby/study/blizz-01.jpg, blitz-03.jpg)
(Errno::ENOENT)
    from c11-photos.rb:29:in `block in <main>'
    from c11-photos.rb:20:in `each'
    from c11-photos.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

First, the program works. All files are accurately moved and renamed. But this error pops up after it's done running. For this particular job, there were only 2 pictures to be moved to a new directory, but notice that the program says it downloaded 4 files. What seems to be happening is that my `#each` method is somehow repeating itself when executed. It's trying to continue moving files even when the target directory has no more picture files to move. I'm guessing this because the "blizz-01.jpg" file is one of the files to be moved, but the "blitz-03.jpg" isn't the name of any file (this is the would-be name if there was a third picture to move). Since "blizz-01.jpg" has already been moved, this would make it give me a "No such file ..." error. Of course, I don't really know if this is what's happening, but that seems to be what the error says.

Why am I getting this error and/or what's wrong with my code that it's producing this problem?

Here's my code:

```
require "yaml"

puts "Where to move the pictures?"
destination = gets.chomp

Dir.chdir "#{destination}"

puts "What shall we name this batch?"
batch = gets.chomp

puts "Where to get your new pictures?"
findpics = gets.chomp

pictures = Dir["#{findpics}/*.{jpg,JPG,JPEG,jpeg,png,PNG}"]

print "Downloading #{pictures.length} files: "

amount = 1

pictures.each do |pic|
print ' . '

newname = if amount < 10
    "#{batch}-0#{amount}.jpg"
else
    "#{batch}-#{amount}.jpg"
end

File.rename pic, newname
amount += 1
end

puts

puts "Operation complete!"
```

Thank you your help!

Answer (score 4):

Case-insensitive filesystem?

`blizz-01.jpg` is matched twice, once by `"#{findpics}/*.jpg"` and once by `"#{findpics}/*.JPG"`, which are two of the expansions of your filesystem glob argument to `Dir[]`.  Same remark for the other file.  Obviously, the second time it's processed in your `each` loop, it's already been renamed.

If you want this to work both on case-sensitive and case-insensitive filesystems, and permit ".jpg" and ".JPG" and so on, you can quickly and simply unique-ify the matches:

```
pictures = Dir["#{findpics}/*.{jpg,JPG,JPEG,jpeg,png,PNG}"].uniq
```

Comment: @7stud, it's an expansion processed in turn.  If I am in a directory with one file, `file.txt`, and do `Dir["*.{txt,txt}"]`, I'll get `["file.txt", "file.txt"]`.  If I'm on a case-insensitive filesystem, I'll get the same for `Dir["*.{txt,TXT}"]`.

Comment: How can that be if the files are matched on a case-sensitive basis (jpg isn't the same as JPG)? I wrote it this way because of case-sensitivity, at first to get only JPGs then expanded it later to get PNGs too (exclude gifs).

Comment: @Proto, I don't follow.  You're on a case-insensitive filesystem under Windows, and ruby's `glob`, used by `Dir[]`, is [at the mercy of the filesystem](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob).  Your files case-insensitively match two patterns each, so they are appended to the results array twice.

Comment: Right, that's what I mean. If it's case sensitive, how is it reading the same file twice? How is it reading blizz01.jpg twice since there is only one blizz01.jpg (there is no blizz01.JPG or .JPEG or other to read a second time).

Comment: @Proto, [the glob is case-_in_sensitive on Windows](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5994).